# Gtts changing the destination

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to generate some .mp3 files, but i don't have control where they are saved! (basically they're saved on the .py's location).
I want to change the save location, it's possible?

```
# -*- coding: <UTF-8> -*-
from gtts import gTTS as gtts
from datetime import datetime as dt

#.MP3 FUNCTIONS FROM GTTS , THIS IS THE STANDARD
def audio_br(words, mp3name, language="pt"):
   teste = gtts(text=words,lang=language)
    teste.save("%s.mp3" % mp3name)

#GET THE TIME TO CREATE MY VARIABLE TO BE TURN ON MP3
tempo = dt.now()
begin = "Olá! são " + str(tempo.hour) + " horas e "+ str(tempo.minute) + "     minutos"
print begin
#GENERATE MY .MP3
audio_br(begin,"A_BEGIN")
```

The problem resides in the fact that the read from gtts don't talk about save path location.

EDIT 1: Sorry for forgiving the code

Comment: Can you show your code? Would like to help but what you've posted is not enough to identify where the problem is. Please consider posting a minimal working code sample to allow others to replicate your problem  and troubleshoot

Comment: @XingzhouLiu there's the code, srry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: <UTF-8> -*-
from gtts import gTTS as gtts
from datetime import datetime as dt
import os

#.MP3 FUNCTIONS FROM GTTS , THIS IS THE STANDARD
def audio_br(words, mp3name, language="pt"):
   teste = gtts(text=words,lang=language)
   teste.save("%s.mp3" % os.path.join(<desired folder>,mp3name))
```

You need to call teste.save with the complete path to where you want the files to go. By default, if no path is provided, python writes files to the current working directory, which is the folder where the script is called from.

Using os.path.join is best b/c it joins paths using the system path separator, making your code more platform independent.

Comment: This going to be a dumb question, but if i wanted to save in a USB drive directory it is possible?(i'm asking that because my usb is not here)

Comment: No worries. You'll need to find the path to your USB drive and pass that in to your script. So on windows it's gonna be <letter>:\... or on  unix like it'll be something like /dev/<partition name>. Again, teste.save will put files at exact location given a complete path, or if not it will put files at a path relative to the path you call your script.

Comment: teste.save("%s.mp3" % os.path.join(<C:\Users\harbinger\Desktop\ENGF57\Voice_Demo>,mp3name) , i'm getting syntax error

Comment: Use teste.save("%s.mp3" % os.path.join('C:\Users\harbinger\Desktop\ENGF57\Voice_Demo',​mp3name). Quotes your strings. Also, the <...> is just my way of saying insert value here, not correct syntactic.

Comment: And if i had it a path like this: 'Este Computador\Kaike Reis\Card\LOST.DIR' with spaces?
And i'm creating a new variable like this (to be more readable to my teacher):
full_path=os.path.join('Este Computador\Kaike Reis\Card\LOST.DIR',mp3name)
but i'm getting this error message:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Este Computador\\Kaike Reis\\Card\\LOST.DIR\\A_BEGIN.mp3'